# Questions regarding this implement of a playing card game

Tags: python, playing-cards

```
from enum import Enum
from enum import IntEnum

class Suits(Enum):
    DIAMONDS="diamonds"
    HEARTS="hearts"
    SPADES="spades"
    CLUBS="clubs"


class Values(IntEnum):
    TWO=2
    THREE=3
    FOUR=4
    FIVE=5
    SIX=6
    SEVEN=7
    EIGHT=8
    NINE=9
    TEN=10
    JACK=11
    QUEEN=12
    KING=13
    ACE=14


deck_of_cards=[]


class Playing_Cards():
    def __init__(self, card_value, card_suit):
        self.card_value=card_value
        self.card_suit=card_suit

deck_of_cards=[]

for suit in Suits:
    for value in Values:
        deck_of_cards.append(Playing_Cards(value,suit))

print(deck_of_cards)
```

I want to print `deck_of_cards` and it's showing a list of objects. Could you please explain why?

```
[<__main__.Playing_Cards object at 0x102268128>,
<__main__.Playing_Cards object at 0x102268198>,
<__main__.Playing_Cards object at 0x1022681d0>, <__main__.Playing_"
```

Questions:

1. Did I add `cards(value, suit)` to the list properly?
2. How can I `print` what is in the list `deck_of_cards`?

Comment: Give your Playing_Cards class `__str__` and `__unicode__` methods.

Comment: it's just printing to the address of the object, look in to a different way of printing a list together, either as a string using `join` or looping through each entry in to the list and printing it

Comment: Python has no idea what you want to happen when you print a `Playing_Cards` instance, unless you tell it. It defaults to that `<main.Playing_Cards object at 0x102268128>` just to have _something_ to print out. If you want something different, define a `__repr__` method and/or a `__str__` method.

Comment: Nominated for reopening as dupe question is about custom string representation of *classes* not *objects*. The solution to each is different enough to warrant different answers. Looking for another suitable answer.

Comment: Generally, you should avoid `IntEnum` unless you are working with legacy code...

Comment: Also, the class should be PlayingCard, singular, since one instance represents a single card.